# Combobox with images items-WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I'm newbie on WPF and I would like to add images items to combobox which will read from hard disk according filter on it's name.

filter on images name should be binds to text property of different element.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a good example to show MVVM approach. Code below will do the job:

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="simplest.MainWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:simplest"
                mc:Ignorable="d"
                Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="outputFolder" Height="30" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Filter}"/>
        <ComboBox Height="30" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image MaxWidth="64" MaxHeight="64" Source="{Binding}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C#**

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _filter;
    private ObservableCollection<string> _images = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private readonly string _filesSearchPath = "d:\\";

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Filter = "*.jpg";
    }


    public string Filter
    {
        get
        {
            return _filter;
        }

        set
        {
            _filter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

            RefreshImagesCollection();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Images
    {
        get
        {
            return _images;
        }
    }

    private void RefreshImagesCollection()
    {
        _images.Clear();
        foreach (var fileName in Directory.GetFiles(_filesSearchPath, _filter))
        {
            _images.Add(fileName);
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ItemTemplate and ItemSource are the properties you need to set.
ItemTemplate should point to Datatemplate and ItemSource to Collection of strings(path to images).
[This](http://www.codescratcher.com/wpf/wpf-combobox-with-image/) link will help you.